# Rspec tests of rack_cache

Tags: ruby-on-rails, caching, rack

I am using rack_cache to cache some of the responses withing Redis. I would like to test with rspec so I would be sure that caching works. I can do this with:

```
config.action_dispatch.rack_cache = true
```

The problem is because I would like to set this setting on single test, not for whole app.

For high level caching we can use around bock:

```
config.around(:each, :caching) do |example|
  caching = ActionController::Base.perform_caching
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = example.metadata[:caching]
  example.run
  ActionController::Base.perform_caching = caching
end
```

Is there a way to do something similar for Rack cache?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ended up deliting redis cache before running tests:

```
redis_keys = $redis.keys('*')
$redis.del(redis_keys) if redis_keys.count > 0
```